# Singleton class persists the values from previous iteration in multithread environment and resetting may result in NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, static, thread-safety, singleton

I have a singleton class that will be used by various other classes to populate the `Map` during the code execution by accessing the single instance. Everything seems to work fine here. But when I again execute the code a second time then the values from the previous iteration persists.

I am aware that this is happening because of the singleton class which is creating a single instance. I am not understanding how to reset it.

Following is the code I have:

```
public class Namespace {

    @Getter
    private Map<String, String> namespaces = null;
    private static volatile Namespace instance;
    private static Object mutex = new Object();

    public static Namespace getInstance() {
        Namespace result = instance;
        if (result == null) {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                result = instance;
                if (result == null)
                    instance = result = new Namespace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Namespace() {
        namespaces = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public void namespacePopulator(String namespaceURI, String prefix) {
        namespaces.put(namespaceURI, prefix);
    }

    public void instanceReset() {
        instance = null;
    }
}
```

Following is the way I am accessing the methods:
At the beginning of the program execution, I am creating the instance of the class. Just so as to reset the `Map` and create a new instance.

```
Namespace namespace = new Namespace();
```

Then I populate the Map something like this:

```
Namespace.getInstance().namespacePopulator("Field1", "Value1");
```

I am aware that I can call the `instanceReset()` method at the end of the execution but I am running this program in a multi-threaded environment and if any of the threads makes a call to `instanceReset()` other threads will start throwing NullPointerException.

I want some workaround or suggestion to handle this situation. All I want to know is how to populate the `Map` from various different classes and modules by sharing the instance using the `Non-Static` and `Multi-thread` approaches.

I saw various examples on singleton but all of them seem to follow the almost identical process. I am not very particular about the singleton approach or any other dedicated way. All I want is the best and efficient way of handling this issue. Any workaround or ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean by instanceReset? Can you not do a clear()? Also, the object is a singleton, but the `put` is not thread-safe without a ConcurrentHashMap or a SynchronizedHashMap

Comment: @aksappy Thanks for the response. `instanceReset()` is a method that is used to clear the `instance` by setting the `instance = null` so that during the next iteration of the program a fresh new instance will be created. Otherwise, the same instance will be used due to which I get values within Map from the previous iteration.

Comment: Okay, change HashMap, which is not thread-safe, to a thread-safe ConccurrentHashMap. Singleton is a creational pattern and thread-safety is guaranteed only when the creating an object. The object itself is not thread-safe.

Comment: @aksappy I am not particular about the `Singleton` or any other pattern. All I am looking for is the best way to address the issue. I want to populate a `Map` from multiple classes in a nonstatic way, thread-safe and memory-efficient way. I am open to all the possible ways. `Singleton` is something that I found during my research and was trying this and ran into a wide variety of issues. If you have any other suggestion then please provide the same.

Comment: Those two changes (which is also what devReddit said) should do the trick.

Comment: The solution is not to use a singleton. Singletons are good immutable objects and, as you have discovered, really bad mutable objects, above all in a multithreaded environment. Obviously, you need an instance of this object per thread, do that then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all the responses. I checked with my mentor and we were able to do something like this. Posting the answer as it can be useful to someone in the future:

This seems to work according to the thread and populate specific Maps. Make sure to clear the Map at the beginning of the application so that every time we will have an empty map and if there is some problem during execution then the map will be half-filled so clearing at the beginning of the code would avoid all these issues and we will be guaranteed to have empty Map.

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Namespaces {
    private static final ThreadLocal < Map < String, String >> NAMESPACE_MAPS = new ThreadLocal < Map < String, String >> () {

        @Override
        protected Map < String, String > initialValue() {
            return new HashMap < > ();
        }
    };

    private static Namespaces instance = new Namespaces();
    public static Namespaces getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized void namespacePopulator(String namespaceURI, String prefix) {
        NAMESPACE_MAPS.get().put(namespaceURI, prefix);

    }

    public synchronized void namespaceReset() {
        NAMESPACE_MAPS.get().clear();
    }

    public Map < String, String > getNamespaces() {
        return NAMESPACE_MAPS.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ConcurrentHashMap` or a `Collections.synchronizedMap`, and do not set them to `null` while `instanceReset`, do a `map.clear()` instead for the maps.

The best solution is: Don't use a singleton if you need mutable things.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any better way to address the issue? rather than clearing every time at the end of execution? I am not particular about the Singleton or any other pattern. All I am looking for is the best way to address the issue. I want to populate a Map from multiple classes in a nonstatic way, thread-safe and memory-efficient way.

Comment: If you have no reason to use a singleton, don't use it. All working around the limitations ist flawed. having to synchronize access to a method makes it slow  and usage fragile - one should do this only if the resource needs it. Your approach with creating a new instance with new Namespace() is against the singleton idea anyway, because this instance created is never used but exists nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

We always have to be double careful while using a singleton class. Singleton object can be easily shared between threads and that's why Singleton objects are dangerous to use. This question is the perfect example of the code which could cause data corruption, but that is not it, this code is a perfect example of bad coding practice as well.

Problem Number 1 -

```
Namespace namespace = new Namespace();
```

A Singleton must have a private constructor. The public constructor will destroy the Singleton nature of the class. Every time a Namespace object gets created, the *map namespaces* gets initialized with null. The function *namespacePopulator* will work on null Map, this will throw NullPointerException. So mark the constructor private.

Problem Number 2 -

```
    public void instanceReset() {
      instance = null;
    }
```

The function *instanceReset* destroy the very aspect of the beautifully written constructor. The function *instanceReset* is not protected by mutex. Let's consider thread T1 is working on the *getInstance* function but at the same time thread T2 is done with *instanceReset* operation, we cannot predict if thread T1 shall get anything from below list.

```
 1. A new instance 
 2. An old instance 
 3. A NULL
```

Problem Number 3 -

Why do we need *instanceReset* function at all? We should use Singleton class only when we are sure that we need only one object of the class throughout the lifecycle of the application. Function *instanceReset* will cause memory leak. For example, let's assume Thread T1 gets a Old Instance of the Namespace (instance created before *instanceReset* called), this instance will never become null and never be garbage collected. This can happen multiple times and Multiple instances will remain in memory and will not be garbage collected. Even adding mutex to the *instanceReset* function will not fix the memory leak problem.

Solution -

```
public class Namespace {

@Getter
private Map<String, String> namespaces = null;
private static volatile Namespace instance;
private static Object mutex = new Object();

public static Namespace getInstance() {
    Namespace result = instance;
    if (result == null) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            result = instance;
            if (result == null)
                instance = result = new Namespace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private Namespace() { // Never make this public
    namespaces = new HashMap<>();
}

public void synchronized namespacePopulator(String namespaceURI, String prefix) 
{  // add synchronized keyword.
    namespaces.put(namespaceURI, prefix);
}

//public void instanceReset() { Never nullify a singleton instance this way. 
//    instance = null;
//}

public void synchronized namespaceReset() {
    namespaces.clear();
}
```

}

Now we can call *namespaceReset* from any thread. We have to keep one thing in mind, this change will be reflected across the threads.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and simple explanation. If I am using the `Synchronized method` then I do not have to make use of `ConcurrentHashMap` right? or its good to make use of both? Also, Is there any better way to address the issue? rather than clearing every time at the end of execution? I am not particular about the Singleton or any other pattern. I want to populate a Map from multiple classes in a nonstatic way, thread-safe and memory-efficient way. All I am looking for is the best way to address the issue.